# Multiple versions of .nib file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

Is there any way to have two .nib files with the same name? I'm using Xcode 4, and I want to have multiple versions of interface i.e: `MainMenu.xib` in different folders, so I can access them with:

`[[MainMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenu" bundle:skinBundle]`

where my `skinBundle` would be bundle from path:

`skinBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"skinFolderPath" ofType:nil]`

When I build application, all directories are flattened resulting only one `MainMenu.nib`. When I add folders as a *folder references*, directory tree is preserved but none of the .xib files are compiled to .nib.

Is there any way to achieve this? Or maybe better way to manage multiple versions of nibs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create additional targets in Xcode called "resource bundles." These have the bundle structure (like .app or .framework bundles) but contain no binary code. Add your resources to those bundles, add the products of those targets to your main target's "Copy Bundle Resources" stage, and then use those bundles during instantiation using code such as the following:

```
NSString *skinBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"MyBundle" ofType: @"skin"]; // or whatever it's called
if (skinBundlePath) {
    NSBundle *skinBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath: skinBundlePath];
}
```

The above snippet assumes you set the target's *wrapper extension* to "skin" and named it "MyBundle".

In Xcode 3 (I don't have 4 handy), you can add a target by going to Project -> New Target. Pick "Loadable Bundle" from Mac OS X (even if you're using iOS.) Off the top of my head, you don't need any further configuration to get it working, but you must take care that resources wind up in the right bundle when you add them.

If that sounds overly complicated, it's also possible to create a new project that builds a loadable bundle, and make that a dependency of your main project; again, add the build product of the subproject to your main project's resources "Copy Bundle Resources" stage.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. In Xcode 4 I've managed to create bundle by choosing project in _Project Navigator_ -> _Add Target_ button-> _Mac OS X Framework & Library_ -> _Bundle_. Then I removed all resource files from application's target _"Copy Bundle Resources"_ stage and add them to the bundle's accordingly. Next I added Bundles to application's _"Target Dependencies"_ stage and dragged bundles from _Products_ group in Project Navigation to _"Copy Bundle Resources"_ in main app.

Comment: I must add that I had to change Bundle's Target build settings: _Base SDK_ to `Latest iOS` and _Supported Platforms_ to `iphonesimulator iphoneos`. Without that, Bundle products wouldn't be in the same directory as main target. Resulting error in _"Copy Bundle Resources"_ stage. Another problem I've encountered is that nibs are caching referenced images on load and when I have two images with the same name in two different bundles, only one will be displayed due the caching by name. Do you have any elegant solution?

Comment: Instead of using `[NSImage imageNamed:]`, use `[NSImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]`. It's less efficient memory-wise but it will prevent that from happening.